# Adding a CFI-Airplane rating to existing CFI-Helicopter Certificate

Tags: faa-regulations, airplane, cfi, logbook-endorsements

Have a student who has CFI-Helicopter, and looking to get CFI-Airplane. Student has his commercial single engine airplane and wants to get CFI Airplane. What endorsements and any other factors will she need? I am aware of what will be on the checkride, by looking in the CFI-A transition table in PTS.

Comment: Does your student have an airplane-instrument rating? And is your student seeking a CFI - Airplane *Single-engine* rating

Comment: The post speaks of one particular student, saying "... has *his* {rating}" but then "what... will *she* need?"  If you want to obscure your student's identify, "has their CSEL" and "what will they need" is fine, but otherwise please write consistently about the individual.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding a Certificated Flight Instructor Category and Class *rating* to the holder of an existing Certificated Flight Instructor *certificate***.

---

In my opinion, the sample (or similar) Instructor endorsements (per AC 61-65H - Certification: Pilots and Flight and Ground Instructors, linked just below) documenting the training provided to and received by the student meet the necessary (endorsement) requirements asked in your question. This is based on someone who currently holds a CFI-Rotorcraft-Helicopter *certificate* and is adding a CFI-Airplane-Single-Engine *rating*. (This also assumes your student has an airplane instrument rating.)

The endorsements referenced by the list below are from [AC 61-65H](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65h.pdf) (beginning in Appendix A):

1. [14 CFR Part 61.39](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.39(a)):  Prerequisites for practical tests: **A.1 and A.2**
2. [14 CFR 61.185(a)(2)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.185(a)): Flight instructor aeronautical knowledge test: **A.42**
3. [14 CFR 61.187 (a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.187(a)): Flight instructor ground and flight proficiency/practical test: **A.43**
4. [14 CFR 61.183 (i)(1)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.183(a)) : Spin training: **A.45**

NOTES:

1. A 25 question written test per 14 CFR 61.185(a)(2), referenced in endorsement A.42 noted above, is required. Several other references show this requirement - see the [FAA AIRMAN KNOWLEDGE TESTING MATRIX Effective April 24, 2023, page 10](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/testing_matrix) .  The knowledge test name is shown as "AFA" Flight Instructor Airplane (Added Rating)*.
2. If the flight test is a "retest" the examiner must test the person on stall awareness, spin entry, spins, and spin recovery instructional procedures in an airplane that is certificated for spins.  This is opposed to having an endorsement, as shown in A.45 above, provided by the instructor.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to meet all the requirements of §61.183 in order for said student to be eligible to take the practical test for CFI-Airplane, single engine.  The chief difference for you, and for this student is going to be they will not be required to take the fundamentals of instruction exam again, as they already hold a CFI certificate with a rotorcraft helicopter category and class rating.  They will be required to take an abbreviated version of the CFI knowledge exam specific to the aircraft category sought (see the [FAA’s knowledge exam matrix](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/testing_matrix)). The transition table listed in the CFI-PTS should cover the pertinent areas of the practical test which the examiner will focus their emphasis on.

Comment: I think my comment addressed that.